# Make Windows go to sleep regardless of playing media

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate, media-player

Is there a way to make Windows 7 sleep/hibernate no matter if a media player is playing music/movies or not?

I'm asking because I've had times when I'm listening to music while I'm on the PC and when I need to go out I forget to turn the music off and my PC stays turned on until I get back (several hours or more).

EDIT: I know that using the button always works. But I'm talking about leaving it an it going to sleep automatically after a few minutes.

Comment: in this case the music program prevents sleep. Which tool do you use?

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
shutdown -h -f -t 0
```

Should do the trick. You can put this in a .bat file and then double-click it to execute. You can set the `-t` flag to the amount of seconds you want it to wait before executing.

Comment: Look at the edit, I'm talking about an automatic sleep/hibernate.

Comment: What do you want the trigger for hibernating to be? You clicking something, or something that senses you being away?

Comment: The mouse not moving for a given amount of minutes. To do what Windows usually does .. just to do it regardless of anything: you're watching a movie but you haven't touched the mouse for 3 minutes so the computer goes to sleep. That's what I want.

Comment: You could use Windows Task Sheduler, and use the "On Idle" trigger, but the problem is that if whatever you're using to play music sets the ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED flag (check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383561(v=vs.85).aspx) on this), this prevents the pc from going to idle. I've googled a little, and haven't found a solution to this.<br> Only thing I can think of is for example connect your smartphone to your pc and have a program hibernate on out-of-range. Or run a webserver in your home-network, and use your smartphone to access it and hibernate the pc.